# Can't install vim-plug

Tags: vim

Following the instructions, I put plug.vim in autoload folder and my vimrc looks like this now:

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
call plug#end()

set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction
```

So I added only

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
call plug#end()
```

On VIM start up I get

```
[vim-plug] `git` executable not found. vim-plug requires git.
```

Using windows 7, please help.

Comment: Do you have `git` installed?

Comment: @FDinoff Yes. downloaded from git-scm site. Is it the right one?

Comment: Probably, you also need to put it in the path so that vim can find it. (As for how I don't know how I don't use windows)

Comment: Should I add something to Windows environment variable or add smth to vimrc? I am vim newbie, how to do that?

Comment: Most likely windows environment variable

Comment: Added C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe and called it git. Did not work. And I do not see why I got a downvote.

Comment: @FDinoff. Its been almost five years since you posted your comment. But ... no I did _not_ have git installed! (Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalled GIT using *Run git from Windows command prompt* option

https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/wiki/Vundle-for-Windows

This sets appropriate PATH variable.

Comment: in Ubuntu do this   ` sudo apt install git` as it is not installed in Ubuntu by default.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error on Linux, and solved by just installing git.

---

### sudo apt update

### sudo apt install git